# How to use Apache Commons Lang code without an IDE? (org.apache.commons.lang3)

Tags: java, import, environment-variables, path-variables, apache-commons-lang3

I am using Amazon Coretto, a JDK, to write and run Java code. I am trying to use a class from Apache Commons Lang with simple import statements like:

`import org.apache.commons.lang3.*`

However, everything I have looked up online will only describe how to do this with an IDE like Eclipse. How do I download the org.apache.commons.lang3 class and use its subclasses with only a JDK?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to install Maven, create a `pom.xml` file and add commons-lang as a dependency.

The minimal way is to download from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.11/commons-lang3-3.11.jar and add the jar to your class path when you compile: `javac -cp commons-lang3-3.11.jar Foo.java` and when you run: `java -cp commons-lang3-3.11.jar:. Foo`

The files you see in your working directory should be `Foo.java` and `commons-lang3-3.11.jar`. After you have run`javac` you will also see `Foo.class`.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the second option, and it gave me this error: `error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist`. How do I fix this?

Comment: You probably don't have the jar where you are telling javac that it is.

Comment: Thank you. Just a head up. There is a typo in the statement running java. Colon to Semicolon. `java -cp commons-lang3-3.11.jar;. Foo`

Comment: That depends on the platform `:` on Linux and OS X, `;` on Windows.